# How to zoom UIScrollView with UIimageview and a third uiimage as overlay on top with fixed width & height

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming, scale

**i have i UIscrollview with a subview wich is UIimageView and when i zoom the scroll view every thing work fine.
like this:**

```
mapImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"]];
mapScrollView.contentSize = mapImageView.frame.size;
[mapScrollView addSubview:mapImageView];
mapScrollView.minimumZoomScale = mapScrollView.frame.size.width / mapImageView.frame.size.width;
mapScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4;
[mapScrollView setZoomScale:mapScrollView.minimumZoomScale];
```

**i add another UIimageview as subview to the uiviewimage in a position, like this:**

```
userImageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble.png"]];
userImageView1.frame = CGRectMake( 300  * 4, 300 * 4, 104 * 4 , 135 * 4  ); 
[mapImageView addSubview:userImageView1];   
[userImageView1 release];
```

**now the bubble moves on the map as i zoom.
in the delegate function i do this:**

```
(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView{
    CGRect frame = userImageView1.frame;
    frame.origin.x = ??
    frame.origin.y = ??
    frame.size.width = 104 /2/_scrollView.zoomScale; 
    frame.size.height = 135 /2/_scrollView.zoomScale;
    userImageView1.frame = frame;   
}
```

**in order to set fixed width & height.**

**my question is whats needs to be the X & Y in order to move the image to the relevant position in the zoomed screen.
how do i calculate those X,Y**

10x

Tamir

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `UIScrollView` is a subview of your main view controller's view, why not just add the fixed width `UIImageView` as a subview of the main view above the `UIScrollView`?

Comment: because then the item will not move on the screen according to the zoom and i need to movement. it will be in fixed location and i will need to implement the movement